I have a few questions about animal fur in blender as well as rigging said character
I want to start by saying I've only been using Blender for roughly 2 weeks as of now. I am still learning the processes, but have made it up to UV unwrapping for my fox character I'm making for my video game. I guess what I'm saying is I have a little bit of understanding of the program, but not enough to find answers through google and am hoping someone here might be able to help me out.

Particle System vs Fur Mesh:
I have seen video of both and have experimented a little bit with both to try and find the results I like. That being said, I'm not sure which one has more flexibility, if either can lead to totally different results, or if they're similar enough that it doesn't matter. I did notice that using a mesh seems to give me a few more options such as pinching, but outside of that I didn't know if there was a whole lot of performance differences or customization options. The videos I've seen using the two have not been the lengthiest or most in depth. Any resources would be appreciated.
Rigging:
Does it matter when I set up to rig my character? Meaning post/pre fur. If I decide later on I don't like the fur, will it cause issues trying to adjust it if I have everything rigged first? Or would it cause issues adding fur later after rigging? I haven't done any rigging as of yet, but most videos I've seen involve characters that appear to be finished. Now that I think about it, does it matter when I rig at all? If I were to make, say, an arm and hand, could I rig the hand to move just because then create the entire human body afterward?
*Edited to add: Also, do I TPose a four legged animal for rigging? Or can I rig it standing on all fours like a normal creature would?
How do I preview my fur:
This is probably the one that bothers me the most because I don't understand Blender well enough. Videos I've seen creating fur start out with showing how they make the fur. At each step though, they show a general animation of how physics would impact the fur at that point in time. How do I preview my fur in motion so I know if it looks the way I want it to?

I appreciate everyone's help in advance! I apologize if these are questions that are asked often, I just couldn't find much over on YouTube and general Google searching.

Topic is quite long, I try to address you in some basics:

There are more than two options actually: mains are meshes, particle system and geometry nodes (curves that get scattered, combed and animated via geometry nodes). As far as I can tell, for an animated fur I would go for Particle system, because it can perform pinching (named Clumping), and it adds the Hair Dynamics Physic functionality you seem to look for (with meshes it would be far more complicated).
Geometry nodes are the best solution for flexibility and customizing, but they can be a little complicated until you get a clear understanding of Geometry nodes in general.

Rigging can be performed after or before, it doesn't matter, only thing: check that Particle modifier is after (under) the Armature modifier in the modifier stack, and its "Use Modifier Stack" option has to be checked in Emission > Source Properties. It's OK to rig in a standard pose for four legged creatures.

for safety, it's better to preview all physics after baking the particle system (in Properties, Enable Hair Dynamics, then go to Cache > Bake). Consider to create a fast render to avoid low realtime Frame rate - for a fast render go to 3D window, menu View > Render Viewport Animation).
About Previewing, it's also important to raise the "Strands Steps" Amount in the Viewport display properties (as much as your PC can handle).





How can we have "needs more focus" as a reason to vote for closing a question while on the other hand encourage people to ask multiple questions at once by answering questions which could easily be separated into at least 3 different topics? I'll give you +1 for the content though.
